# .NET Maui Binding a contentview to parent ViewModel MVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a xaml page that contains two instances of the same content view. The content view have a datepicker which should update a value in the parent view model ( each content view should update a different variable in the view model). I tried to do the bindiable property but it's not working. I set the BindingMode to TwoWay but that's not working.

The issue is that the binding is not working from the contentview to the parent viewmodel through the bindiable property. Any input is much appreciated.

Below is my code:
MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}"
             xmlns:picker="clr-namespace:TestSync.View"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:TestSync.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:TimeTrackerViewModel"
             x:Class="TestSync.MainPage">

    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedDate}"/>

        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedDate1}"/>

        <picker:DateTimePickerContentView CardTitle="First DatePicker" CardDate="{Binding SelectedDate,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        
        <picker:DateTimePickerContentView CardTitle="Second DatePicker" CardDate="{Binding SelectedDate1,Mode=TwoWay}" />
 
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

TimeTrackerViewModel.cs

```
namespace TestSync.ViewModel
{
    public partial class TimeTrackerViewModel :ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public DateTime selectedDate;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public DateTime selectedDate1;
    }
}
```

DateTimePickerContentView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:TestSync.View"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:DateTimePickerContentView"
             x:Class="TestSync.View.DateTimePickerContentView"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <Label Text="{Binding CardTitle}"/>
        <DatePicker x:Name="myDate" Date="{Binding CardDate}" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

and DateTimePickerContetntView.xaml.cs

```
namespace TestSync.View;

public partial class DateTimePickerContentView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CardTitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CardTitle), typeof(string), typeof(DateTimePickerContentView), string.Empty);

    public string CardTitle
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(DateTimePickerContentView.CardTitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(DateTimePickerContentView.CardTitleProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty CardDateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CardDate), typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimePickerContentView), defaultValue:DateTime.Parse("12/15/1992"),defaultBindingMode:BindingMode.TwoWay,propertyChanged:test);

    private static void test(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var mytest= bindable as DateTimePickerContentView;
        mytest.myDate.Date = (DateTime)newValue;
    }

    public DateTime CardDate
    {
        get => (DateTime)GetValue(DateTimePickerContentView.CardDateProperty);
        set => SetValue(DateTimePickerContentView.CardDateProperty, value);
    }
    public DateTimePickerContentView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: the DatePicker should be bound to its own CardDate property

Comment: @Jason I tried that but that didn't work as well. the selectedDate and selectedDate1 in the view model value not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give you a workaround here.

For DateTimePickerContentView.xaml, define the BindingContext

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         ...
         x:Name="this">

    <VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference this}">
        <Label Text="{Binding CardTitle}"/>
        <DatePicker x:Name="myDate" Date="{Binding CardDate}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

So for DateTimePickerContentView.cs, just delete this line

```
...
public DateTimePickerContentView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //BindingContext = this;
}
```

For data binding in a ContentView, you could refer to this official doc: [Define the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview?view=net-maui-7.0#define-the-ui).

And if you want to set a default value, you should set it in **TimeTrackerViewModel**, because TimeTrackerViewModel's constructor execute after custom control set the default value. Then it will be replaced such as 1/1/1900 .

```
public TimeTrackerViewModel()
{
    SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse("12/15/1992");
    SelectedDate1 = DateTime.Parse("12/15/1992");
}
```

Hope it works for you.