# .NET Maui Binding a contentview to parent ViewModel MVVM Programmatically

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have a view of a listView which in turn contains an ItemTemplateSelector. In one of the ItemTemplateSelector I have a ContentView created programmatically that has a **BindableProperty** that I bind when I'm creating the DataTemplate, but it doesn't load the value that I bring in my ViewModel. I have seen that in the ContentView in the XAML an **x:name="this"** is added and then in the container a **bindingContext={x:Reference this}** is done but how to do that **programmatically**?

The issue is that the binding is not working from the contentview to the parent viewmodel through the bindiable property. Any input is much appreciated.

1. View

```
public class QuestionWithSelectorView : ContentPage
{
    public QuestionWithSelectorView(QuestionsViewModel vm)
    {
        BindingContext = vm;
        this.Title = "Questions";

        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.RowDefinitions = Rows.Define(GridLength.Star, GridLength.Auto);

        var radListView = new RadListView();
        radListView.ItemsSource = vm.Questions;
        radListView.ItemTemplateSelector = new QuestionTypeTemplateSelector();


        grid.SetRow(radListView, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(radListView);

        Content = grid;
    }
}
```

2. Create DataTemplate

```
private static DataTemplate CreateMultipleOptionTemplate()
        {
            return new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var grid = new Grid();
                grid.RowDefinitions = Rows.Define(GridLength.Auto, GridLength.Auto, GridLength.Auto, GridLength.Star);

                var bindingQuestionName = new Binding(nameof(Question.QuestionName), BindingMode.Default);
                var bindingQuestionNumber = new Binding(nameof(Question.QuestionNumber), BindingMode.Default);

                var label = new Label();
                label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, bindingQuestionNumber);
                label.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
                label.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                grid.SetRow(label, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(label);

                var label2 = new Label();
                label2.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, bindingQuestionName);
                label2.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
                label2.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                grid.SetRow(label2, 1);
                grid.Children.Add(label2);

                var bindingOptionsNumber = new Binding(nameof(Question.QuestionOptionNumber), BindingMode.TwoWay);

                var label3 = new Label();
                label3.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, bindingOptionsNumber);
                label3.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
                label3.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                grid.SetRow(label3, 2);
                grid.Children.Add(label3);

                var bindingOptionsNumber2 = new Binding(nameof(Question.QuestionOptionNumber), BindingMode.TwoWay);
                //source: new RelativeBindingSource(RelativeBindingSourceMode.FindAncestorBindingContext,
                //        typeof(QuestionsViewModel)));
                var multipleOptionView = new MultipleOptionView();
                multipleOptionView.SetBinding(MultipleOptionView.OptionsNumberProperty, bindingOptionsNumber2);

                grid.SetRow(multipleOptionView, 3);
                grid.Children.Add(multipleOptionView);

                return new ListViewTemplateCell { View = grid };
            });
        }
```

3. ContentView

```
public class MultipleOptionView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty OptionsNumberProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OptionsNumber), typeof(int), typeof(MultipleOptionView), 9);
    public MultipleOptionView()
    {
        
    }

    public int OptionsNumber { get; set; }

    void CreateView()...
   

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if (propertyName != null)
        {
            if (propertyName == "OptionsNumber")
            {
                if (OptionsNumber != 0)
                {
                    CreateView();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding source to the binding with a RelativeBindingSourceMode, but it didn't work

Comment: MAUI and XF are two different frameworks, please choose the appropriate tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? You can refer to [.NET Maui Binding a contentview to parent ViewModel MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75466143/net-maui-binding-a-contentview-to-parent-viewmodel-mvvm).